# How to override the default layout manager for a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

How does one override the default layout manager for a `JPanel` descendant? I have my own class and want `null` to be the default.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `JPanel` constructors, which accept a `LayoutManager`:

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel() {
        this(true);
    }

    public MyPanel(boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(null, isDoubleBuffered);
    }

    public MyPanel(LayoutManager layout, boolean isDoubleBuffered) {
        super(layout, isDoubleBuffered);
    }

    public MyPanel(LayoutManager layout) {
        this(layout, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an initializer block to your subclass:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    {
         setLayout(null);
    }

    // ... class implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new MyLayout());
```

or

```
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```